# Find min values between n dates given m ranges

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of dates and values

```
[
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-24T01:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-27T04:00:00",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-25T03:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-26T04:00:00",
    "value": 14
  },
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-22T01:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-25T11:00:00",
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-24T01:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-27T04:00:00",
    "value": 22
  },
  ...
]
```

What I want is the list of minimum values for a given time range given all objects given.
So the output would be a non overlapping list of objects with minimum values like so

```
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-22T01:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-24T01:00:00",
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-24T01:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-25T03:00:00",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-25T03:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-26T04:00:00",
    "value": 14
  },
  {
    "start_ts": "2022-10-26T04:00:00",
    "end_ts": "2022-10-27T04:00:00",
    "value": 20
  }
]
```

My current algo is like this
min_days is my final list
ranges is the original list
current range is the current range we're iterating through
if min_days is empty -> append range
elif current range is outside of all ranges, prepend or append it
otherwise find the ranges from within our ranges that overlap with the current range
find the range where the current ranges start_ts > ranges[i] start_ts and current ranges start_ts < ranges[i+1] start ts
same thing for end ts
This gives us the indexes we need to insert/modify into with our new range

Then we get into the meat of the algo

1. Plug in any holes between ranges datetimes
   So if there are any gaps in time from within the ranges we know our current range overlaps with, plus them with our new value
2. Set any overlapping range that has a higher floor to the new range floor
3. If our end_ts of the new_range is > the end_ts of ranges[-1] we need to append a new range to the back

   - This should only happen if the end_ts is > than all other ranges in the entire range list.
   - Same with start_ts
4. As a result of the previous steps some of our ranges may have the same eth price. We can combine these into one range

The result of this is a billion edge cases and counting. There has to be a MUCH cleaner way but I'm lost. If someone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful

Edit: This is an inverted variation on the skylines problem.

Edit2: I need to be able to update the result with a new value easily and relatively quickly. It seems that the common solutions to the skylines problem can't do this. I think my original algorithm is solid as I think it is O(n log(m)) ? As well as being log(n) to insert a new record.

Comment: Look into the Skyline Problem

Comment: Use `heapq min heap` and store your objects as min heap.

Comment: @DillonDavis I took a look at the skyline problem, specifically the python version of this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-skyline-problem-set-2/ 
That is the same problem I'm trying to solve for (inverted), but my issue with these solutions is that, given an already solved set of values, insert one more value into the already solved set. I would need to break it out and rerun the entire algo. With my current algo the time to insert one more value into the completed set is log(n), instead of n log(n) to run the whole thing again. Am I misunderstanding something or is that correct?

Comment: @daneholmberg correct.  I did not realize you would be continuously updating the interval set.